# Access VBA Combo Box Reference

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, recordset

I am running into a snag on the code below. When the code runs, values are being placed on "tblPrepayments", with the exception of the AccountID value.  The me.cboAccountID.column(2) is on "frmInvoices", which pulls in the AccountID, but displays a clients name for usability reasons.

I don't get any errors, but the value is not pulling into "tblPrepayments".  What am I missing? Please let me know if you need additional clarification.

```
If [Rec'd_Prepayments] <> "0.00" And [Prepayment_Month] <> "" Or [Prepayment_Year] <> "" Then
    Dim RecSet As Recordset
    Set RecSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPrePayments")
    RecSet.AddNew
        RecSet![AccountID] = me.cboAccountID.column(2)
        RecSet![Prepayment_Month] = "Billing_Month"
        RecSet![Prepayment_Year] = "Billing_Year"
        RecSet![Rec'd_Prepayment] = "Prepayment1"
    RecSet.Update
End If
End Sub
```

If I run `MsgBox me.cboAccountID.column(2)`, I get a run time error '94': *Invalid use of Null*. If I change the code to `Msgbox me.cboAccountID.column(1)`, I get the client's name, not the ID, and subsequently an error for mismatched data types.

Here is the row source for *cboAccountID*.

```
SELECT tblClientLists.[AccountID], [tblClientLists].Invoice_To
FROM tblClientLists
ORDER BY [Invoice_To];
```

Comment: What is the value returned by `me.cboAccountID.column(2)` when you `AddNew`?

Comment: @HansUp No value is returned.  The new record is generated, but that field is blank.  If I run MsgBox me.cboAccountID.column(2) I get a run time error '94': Invalid use of Null.  If I change the code to Msgbox me.cboAccountID.column (1) I get the clients name, not the ID, and subsequently an error for mis-matched data types.  Not sure if this will help but here is the control source for cboAccountID. SELECT tblClientLists.[AccountID], [tblClientLists].Invoice_To FROM tblClientLists ORDER BY [Invoice_To];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combobox values are 0 based, so you're looking for Me.cboAccountID.column(0) or Me.cboAccountID.Value should also work here.